# Making ImageView align right of screen by Translate animation

Tags: android, alignment, android-animation, translate-animation

The ImageView is larger than the screen width. I want it to move (translate) to the left, so its right side end up align with the right of its parent (screen).

```
.______.                         .______.            
|      |                         |      |
|...............         ................
.     image    .   -->   .    image     .
................         ................
|______|                         |______|
```

**mv_anim.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
  android:toXDelta="-100%p"
  android:duration="50000"
  android:repeatMode="reverse"
  android:repeatCount="infinite">
</translate>
</set>
```

I think I could do it by setting `toXDleta` to `-(imageWidth - screenWidth)` by code.

But I'd like to keep everything simple and not use code at all. Is there a easier way to achieve this by using the XML anim file only?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageView` is not bigger that the screen width. Everything is contained by the bounds of the `Window` (aka screen). The image inside the `ImageView` is off because it's too big. Use `setScaleType(FIT_END)` to place your image.